# take email photo and send it to twitter

Tags: email, twitter, mime, postfix-mta, procmail

An email arrives on the mail server with a foto attached (a motion warning from a security camera, for example) and I would like to forward that foto to a twitter account via a DM. I think I have all the tools necessary to do this, but I haven't gotten them all together.

1. postfix
2. oysttyer
3. procmail
4. ImageMagick
5. dovecot (can add sieve/pigeonhole)
6. root access to install anything else

Currently I am able to send a text message saying "there was a motion warning with a photo, please check email" but that is suboptimal.

The solution I am thinking is best (though I am open o anything) is to figure out how to extract the image from the email and save it to a http accessible location on the server, then link to that location in the DM. However, I am open to any other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have a working (if terrible) solution.

First, using ripmime I pipe the message to ripmime from within procmail. This produces a bunch of garbage files, along with an image file that I want. I proud these files in a web folder, and then I run a cron task to test the URL to the image and delete the garbage files.

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE="/usr/local/www/photodrop/"
PHOTO=`find $BASE -cmin -2 -type f -name="*.jpg" -exec basename {} \;`

URL="http://www.example.com/photodrop/$PHOTO"
echo $URL

oysttyer -runcommand="/dm @[user] $URL"
```

In procmail, I simply pipe the message to ripmime

```
:0
| ripmime -i - -v -d /usr/local/www/photodrop/
```

I looked at several other mime packages (munpack for one) but they didn't like accepting piped messages and munpack specifically required a path to a file, so that was no good. So, this works. Barely.

For security, I remove the images (actually, I move them) after 5 minutes.

Comment: I recall the Perl [`MIME::Tools`](http://search.cpan.org/~dskoll/MIME-tools-5.508/lib/MIME/Tools.pm) package used to come with a script called [`mimeexplode`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DSKOLL/MIME-tools-5.508/examples/mimeexplode) which might be easier to adapt to your needs (specifically, to extract only images).

Comment: thanks. I'll take a look at that. Fo far, it is working OK for my needs, though as a generic solution it pretty much blows. I have regrouped since posting and am now sending all the alerts to a slack channel instead, but the logic is the same, just using curl to post to slack instead of Oysttyer to post to twitter.

Comment: The `--no-nameless` option to `ripmime` might get rid of most or even all of the "garbage" files, but this depends on the input.  You have not shown us a representative input message so this is somewhat speculative, obviously.